# logout application but not logout facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

what is the params in getLogoutUrl means? I know getLogoutUrl itself is log out from facebook. is it possible let the user to logout my application but not logout facebook?

```
if ($user) {

    $params = array('next' => 'http://something.com/logout.php');
    $logout = $facebook -> getLogoutUrl($params);
    $_SESSION['logout'] = $logout;

} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

    <?php if ($user): ?>

         <a href=" <?php echo $_SESSION['logout']; ?> ">Logout</a>

    <?php else: ?>
```

Comment: Well you can destroy your session and the `fb_` cookies set under your domain. But please be aware, that Platform Policies _require_ you to offer the user a possibility to log out of your site _and_ Facebook at the same time.

Comment: @CBroe logout my website but log out facebook make the UX bad..

Comment: You can offer both options if you like, but you _have_ to offer logout from Facebook as well. (Imagine a user not being logged into Facebook before, and using Facebook to login to your site. They will be logged in to FB in the background, and if they log out from your site only and leave the computer, then their Facebook account would be open to the next person using the machine …)

Comment: @CBroe so it's facebook policy?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/, I. 6.: _“Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs the user out of Facebook.”_

Comment: That policy statement doesn't seem to be there anymore.